# If I get a new Destiny disk, will I still be able to play my old saves on the new disk?

Tags: destiny

The title pretty much explains it all.

Comment: LOL... i gave u an upvote though...

Answer (score 12):

Yes, game saves are not in any way tied to the disc.

So long as you are on the same family of consoles using the same online (XBL/PSN) account, your characters will be available to you in Destiny.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @AhkamNihardeen what down votes?

Comment: For the main question

Comment: I would imagine the downvotes are because discs are read only media so there would be no possibility of save data being saved to the disc. I guess you could argue that there might be some unique identifier on each disc that a savegame is tied to but that has been done on no game ever that I know of so it seems like a strange question to be asking. Though for the record I didn't downvote. Lack of what I consider common knowledge does not necessarily make it a bad question.

Comment: Indeed, just makes it an uninformed question. I think he might be thinking of games that have CD keys like PC games for instance. Event then you could use a different disk to play it after installation (afair).